# Using one probability scenario to model another

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose you have a dice that's biased. Side $1, \ldots 6$ come up with probabilities $p_{1} \ldots p_{6}$ respectively.

I want to model a fair coin.
So, I think the best way to do this is to flip twice. If you get something between $1-3$ followed by $4-6$ then it's heads. The other way, it's tails. If you get two things in the same interval, then just reroll twice.

What's the expected number of tosses I'll need to do in terms of $p_{1} \ldots p_{6}$?

Comment: You need merely model your die as having two outcomes:  $P[1 \to 3] = p_1 + p_2 + p_3$ and $P[4 \to 6] = p_4 + p_5 + p_6 = 1 - P[1 \to 3]$.

Answer (score 0):

Define $P_a = p_1 + p_2 + p_3$ and $P_b = p_4 + p_5 + p_6 = 1 - P_a$.  The chance you must re-roll is $P_x \equiv P_a^2 + (1 - P_a)^2$.

The expected number of rolls is:

$${\cal E}(n) = {\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty n P_x^n \over \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty P_x^n}$$

Comment: I understand up to $P_{x}$, but how did you jump from that equation to $E(n)$? In addition, can't this be simplified using the sum of an infinite geometric series?

Comment: The expectation:  take the value $n$ and the probability you get that value, and add up each and normalize.  Yes, you can simplify the infinite sum.

Comment: Thanks. Does the sum start at $0$ or $1$? This isn't clear to me.

Comment: Shouldn't the summation contain only even values of $n$, since we're rolling two at a time?

Comment: For the summation, $n$ counts the *paired* rollings.